# Blade Laravel (Erro ao Exibir texto)

Tags: php, laravel

Ola, estou usando o blade para mostrar dados, o problema q quando uso  as funções  **ucwords** e **strtolower** não é exibido. (sem as funções da certo, porém o texto fica feio, ou todo maiúsculo, ou  ,minusculo pq os clientes não cadastram seguindo um padrão. eu poderia fazer a conversão no cadastro, porém é intrigante isso ). Preciso ativar alguma extensão?

**(Estou usando Xampp, localhost)**

```
{{ ucwords(strtolower($produto->produto)) }}
```

Comment: Podes rastrear qual é a que está a falhar sff. Usa uma de cada vez e vẽ se/qual falha

Comment: @Miguel Obrigado, pesquisei, oq eu vi que existe outra função: mb_strtolower , não sei se o strtolower é para servidores mais antigos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `{!! !!}` ao invés de `{{ }}`

```
{!! ucwords(strtolower($produto->produto)) !!}
```

Comment: Sua solução resolve, mas palavras com acentuação fica desconfigurado, estou usando 

 {{ ucwords(mb_strtolower($produto->produto)) }} 

deu certo.

Comment: Mas o problema que você relatou era apenas que a palavra não aparecia. Logo, apenas respondi o que resolveria essa questão. O que veio depois é por causa de outra causa.

Comment: @JonasFerreira se a resposta foi a solução do seu problema, porque não aceita-lá ?

Comment: Pq eu to procurando aonde faz isso, eu nunca usei esse site kkk; Me ajuda ai. @VirgilioNovic

Comment: @JonasFerreira abaixo da seta apontada pra baixo tem um check é só clicar em cima! do check é claro kkk

Answer (score 0):

**Solução** - usei a função `mb_strtolower`

```
{{ ucwords(mb_strtolower($produto->produto)) }}
```